# UI Test iOS 13 - Textfield retaining old value after being cleared

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios13, xcode-ui-testing

On iOS13 I've noticed that after a textfield is cleared programatically the value for that textfield in the UI tests doesn't update.

In my UI test:

1. Text is entered into the textfield.
2. Some action happens which causes my code to clear the textfield (in this case tapping return on the on screen keyboard).
3. The value of the textfield is checked and it still contains the text that was present before it was cleared.

Here is the code I'm using to clear the textfield:

```
    func clearInput() {
       textField.text = nil
    }
```

Here is the check I'm using in my UI test:

`XCTAssert((createPasswordPage.passwordSecureTextField.value as? String) == "")`

This fails on iOS13 but passes on older versions such as iOS12.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Example:

**Code**

```
class PasswordViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

  ...
        
   @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // Clear the text
    textField.text = nil   
   }

}
```

**UI Test**

```
func testTextClearing() {
    let page = PasswordPage()
    
    // Enter text
    page.passwordTextField.tap()
    page.passwordTextField.typeText("some text")
 
    // Tap button causing text to clear from the textfield 
    page.button.tap()
    
    XCTAssert((page.passwordTextField.value as? String) == "")
}
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: add `print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)` before the assert and share results

Comment: Are your text fields inside of a UITableViewCell? If so, UITableView does some accessibility caching that can cause really odd issues such as this. If this is the case, a simple workaround is adding and removing a UIView from the contentView of the table view cell, which will invalidate the accessibility cache.